# How to generate 2 pixel BMP image with Awk?

Tags: image, awk, bitmap

sorry for the silly question, but I'm trying to create (generate) a simple BMP image 2x1, 24-bit bitmap with pixel format RGB24, using Awk.

Format is "BitmapFileHeader (2+4+4+4=14 bytes) + DIBHeader (4+4+4+2+2+4+4+4+4+4+4=40 bytes) = 54byte", then start of pixel array (bitmap data). Here is my simple script:

```
BEGIN {
ORS="";
filebmp="Image.bmp"
# BMP Header: 2+4+4+4=14 bytes
printf("%c%c",66,77)>filebmp;
printf("%c%c%c%c",62,0,0,0)>filebmp;
printf("%c%c%c%c",0,0,0,0)>filebmp;
printf("%c%c%c%c",54,0,0,0)>filebpm;

# DIB Header: 4+4+4+2+2+4+4+4+4+4+4=40 bytes
printf("%c%c%c%c",40,0,0,0)>filebmp;
printf("%c%c%c%c",2,0,0,0)>filebmp;
printf("%c%c%c%c",1,0,0,0)>filebmp;
printf("%c%c",1,0)>filebmp;
printf("%c%c",24,0)>filebmp;
printf("%c%c%c%c",0,0,0,0)>filebmp;
printf("%c%c%c%c",8,0,0,0)>filebmp;
printf("%c%c%c%c",19,11,0,0)>filebmp;
printf("%c%c%c%c",19,11,0,0)>filebmp;
printf("%c%c%c%c",0,0,0,0)>filebmp;
printf("%c%c%c%c",0,0,0,0)>filebmp;

# start of pixel array (bitmap data)
# Blu pixel
printf ("%c%c%c",127,0,0)>filebmp;
# Green pixel
printf ("%c%c%c",0,127,0)>filebmp;
# Padding
printf ("%c%c",0,0)>filebmp;
}
```

it's works (image below): it generates a BMP image 2x1 and 62 byte size.

http://i60.tinypic.com/mlihyt.jpg

But, now, if in the bitmap data I substitute 127 value with 128 (e.g. in blue pixel), same script Awk generates a BMP image 2x1 but 63 byte size and with "other colours" (see image below)!

http://i62.tinypic.com/2ltkjlg.png

I wonder where I am going wrong...

...any ideas?

Thanks & Bye

Comment: I ran your script as you posted, and then again with 128's instead of 127's, and wasn't able to reproduce the problem.  Both results at 62 chars, and a binary diff showed only the expected 0x80 where 0x7F had been. I did notice a typo in what your posted: `filebpm` instead of `filebmp` for one of the file names.  Are you sure what you've posted is exactly what you are running? (Not that that in itself would explain what you're seeing.)

Comment: also, `man ascii` will show you that `127` is the last `%c` value in the table. So its not certain that 128 for a `%c` is defined. Interesting problem use of awk. Good luck!

Comment: Ooh, I see in your output hex bytes `c2 80`, which happens to be the UTF8 encoding for the 0x80 (decimal 128) control character.  I think we're getting somewhere ...

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do it with `awk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue with gawk. It seems that gawk chooses the output encoding based on your `LANG` environment variable. (Here I've change both instances of 127 to 128.)

```
$ LANG=en_US.LATIN1 gawk -f bit.awk
$ wc -c Image.bmp
  62 Image.bmp

00000000: 424d 3e00 0000 0000 0000 3600 0000 2800  BM>.......6...(.
00000010: 0000 0200 0000 0100 0000 0100 1800 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0800 0000 130b 0000 130b 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 8000 0000 8000 0000       ..............

$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 gawk -f bit.awk
$ wc -c Image.bmp
  64 Image.bmp

00000000: 424d 3e00 0000 0000 0000 3600 0000 2800  BM>.......6...(.
00000010: 0000 0200 0000 0100 0000 0100 1800 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0800 0000 130b 0000 130b 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 c280 0000 00c2 8000 0000  ................
```

Run gawk under a single-byte encoding and you should be fine.

Comment: LANG environment variable was set-up to LANG=it_IT.UTF8.
I have changed LANG localisation from it_IT.UTF8 to it_IT@euro e now it works.

I really thank you all for joining me in this "little problem".

Comment: Great analysis. Using `LC_ALL=C gawk -f bit.awk` is probably the most robust approach. It's also interesting to note that neither BSD `awk` nor `mawk` exhibit this behavior.